# When did korbanot become a Jewish thing?

Tags: korban, bechor-firstborn

Cain and Abel and Noah did traditional offerings. Abraham did some odd ritual involving cutting animals in half and walking through them, Yaakov poured some oil on a rock. But does do a real sacrifice before leaving Israel. God tells Moshe to ask Pharaoh to let the Jews do some offerings but they don't actually do that. The Pesach isn't described as an offering to God. Moshe builds an altar in the desert after the battle with Amalek but no further details are given.

Were the Jewish people in Egypt accustomed to burning animal parts on an altar to God before the Mishkan was built? Did the firstborn do this? On what occasions did they do this?

Comment: Never was a jewish thing. See the Rambam who says that all goyim can bring korbonos on a bama even nowadays. See Shkalim as well.

Comment: Bereishit 46:1 is pretty unambiguous

Comment: "_Were the Jewish people in Egypt accustomed to burning animal parts on an altar to God before the Mishkan was built? Did the firstborn do this?_" Considering your introduction, why not assume the answer to be, "No, they didn't"? (In other words, why does the question come up, for you?)

Comment: The reason I ask is because I am trying to understand the word "kohen" in shemita 19:22. If the firstborn are the Kohanim, as Rashi states, what religious services did they perform?

Comment: @ClintEastwood (1) Then, that should be in the question itself. (2) It could just mean that the firstborn were consecrated/dedicated for the service before of God, they left Egypt, with the understanding that the specifics of that service would be revealed at a latter date. (If not for the Golden Calf debacle, they would have been performing the services, that Aharon, his sons, and the Levites ended up doing.)

Comment: I don't want to taint the answers by framing the question.

Comment: @ClintEastwood I'd say the cat is out of the bag by now, and for the "untainted" question the problem in my first comment still stands.

Comment: It is not really a Jewish thing to offer sacrifices.

Comment: [G-d said to David:] One day that you sit and busy yourself with Torah [study] is better to me than a thousand offerings that your son Solomon will bring on the alter. (Shabbat 30a).

Comment: Charity is greater than all the sacrifices. (Sukkah 49b).

Comment: Funny you should ask about this, because I just published an essay on this topic: https://www.mdpi.com/2077-1444/12/5/363/htm

Answer (score 0):

The initial part of your question seems to be part of a discussion about the definition of "Jewish," and I'm not sure what qualifies as "accustomed," but we do have an example of a 'classic' animal korban post-exodus, pre-mishkan:

**"burning animal parts on an altar to God"**

At the end of Parshat Mishpatim (24:4-5) it says:

> ויכתב משה את כל־דברי ה' וישכם בבקר **ויבן מזבח** תחת ההר ושתים עשרה מצבה לשנים עשר שבטי ישראל. וישלח את־נערי בני ישראל **ויעלו עלת ויזבחו זבחים שלמים לה' פרים**.

> And Moshe wrote all the words of G-d and arose in the morning and **built an altar** below the mountain and twelve monuments for twelve tribes of Yisrael. And he sent the youths of Bnei Yisrael and **they gave olah-offerings [burnt-offerings] and shlamim-offerings [peace-offerings] of bulls to G-d.**

**"before the Mishkan was built"**

The Mishkan hasn't even been commanded at this point.

**"Did the firstborn do this?"**

> [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.24.5?lang=he&with=Rashi&lang2=he): את נערי – הבכורות
> "The youths" - the firstborns

This isn't universally agreed-upon, but it's pretty widespread; see for example [Rashbam](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Dual/Rashbam/Shemot/24.5#m7e0n6), [ibn Ezra](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Dual/Ibn_Ezra_First_Commentary/Shemot/24.5#m7e0n6), [Bechor Shor](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Dual/R._Yosef_Bekhor_Shor/Shemot/24.5#m7e0n6), [R' Avraham ben haRambam](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Dual/R._Avraham_b._HaRambam/Shemot/24.5#m7e0n6), [Baal haTurim](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Dual/Tur_Long_Commentary/Shemot/24.5#m7e0n6), and others.

> Ralbag says:
> כי לא היו שם כהנים עדיין.
> Because there weren't kohanim yet.